# Flip C# Telerik image from being upside down

Tags: c#, telerik

I am attempting to past an image onto a pdf using Telerik in C#. The following code adds the image, but it's upside down. Telerik seems to paste it upside down no matter what rotation type I use on `RotateFlip`. The image should display UnUnU, but it's upside down and displays NuNuN. I added the image into the below code in base64.

**How can I flip the image?**

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])Convert.FromBase64String("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")))
{
    Image tmpimage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    tmpimage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
    tmpimage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    var image = page.Content.AddImage(new ImageSource(ms));
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Calling `Image.Save` does not overwrite the data in the stream you provide it, it adds to it. This means the original image is still there. Try making a new `MemoryStream`, saving to it, and adding it to your page. Update your question with the result if that doesn't work.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks!! Got it working! haha super simple now that I know how it works!